# Using Lua modules in Nginx

Tags: nginx, lua

I am using Nginx + Lua. I do have a Lua module, which I am trying to access from Nginx and I do get some errors.

Below is my Lua module.

```
local _M = {}

function Set (list)
  local set = {}
  for _, l in ipairs(list) do set[l] = true end
  return set
end

local items = Set { "Apple", "Pear", "Banana" }

local mt = { __index = _M }

function _M.new(self)
    return setmetatable({items=items}, mt)
end

function _M.isFruit(self, item)
  if self.items[item] then
    return true
  end
  return false
end

return _M
```

Now I try to access this in Nginx's access_by_lua directive as show below

```
local f = require "fruits"
local fruit = f:new()
fruit:isFruit("Apple")
```

Here I get an error as below.

> lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: access_by_lua:3: attempt to call method 'isFruit' (a nil value)

I don't understand what is going wrong. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

I am using Nginx 1.6.2 with Lua JIT 2.0.2

EDIT: Corrected the line number in the error message.

Comment: Does it work outside of nginx?

Comment: That worked in my env, where's the line 7 in your access_by_lua?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, I have tried in Openresty and it works.

Comment: @danielgpm, Sorry for the misleading line number. Please read it as line number 3. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble with lua, there's a python module [here](https://github.com/arut/nginx-python-module). I know that lua is not very widespread so many of you have never tried it, while python is very widespread these days. I tried and it seems to be great.